# Is it still possible to submit Apps built with the ios 4 SDK?

Tags: ios5

How long can Apps be submitted, that are built with the iOS4 SDK. My App is not working with iOS5 (graphical issues) and it would be a lot easier to submit an update built with 4SDK (this runs well on iOS5 devices). Is that still possible?

Is there a document from Apple, since when iOS4 build Apps can be submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had a iOS app built with the iOS4 SDK approved for the USA iTunes App Store, so you apparently can still submit apps buit with a iOS4 SDK.